# Missing "System.Drawing" in Global Assembly Cache package install with NuGet

Tags: c#, ravendb, nuget, selenium-webdriver, nuget-package

I recently dealt with some "dependency hell" version conflicts with JSON.Net trying to use RavenDB and Selenium Webdriver in the same library, and hence I reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 (in that order) in the process.

This is the error I get when trying to install Selenium WebDriver using NuGet GUI in visual studio 2012.

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetZip (≥ 1.9.1.8)'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.10'.
Successfully installed 'DotNetZip 1.9.1.8'.
Successfully installed 'Selenium.WebDriver 2.25.1'.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.10' to [project-name].
Successfully added 'DotNetZip 1.9.1.8' to [project-name].
Successfully uninstalled 'Selenium.WebDriver 2.25.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'DotNetZip 1.9.1.8'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.10'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Failed to add reference to 'System.Drawing'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
```

This command worked fine before the mess.  I created a project and successfully compiled and ran a program using System.Drawing, so VS2012 can indeed see the library.

My previous problem instigating the reinstalls, is that my VC/C++ compiler could not include any base C libraries, like stdio.lib, etc.  This is still unresolved, but not the point of this question since I abandoned compiling from source.

**Update**

The problem was solved by creating a new project, coypying files, and doing a Nuget installs there.  Still the error is very strange.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Even the project dependencies for GAC assembles showed with a yellow exclamation in VS. An alternative approach that worked for me was to remove the `.nuget` solution folder, and then right-click the solution and select `Enable NuGet Package Restore`. After this, the project built fine and the exclamations disappeared. Nuget was also able to install dependencies without issues.

Comment: I had the same issue because I was adding Webdriver into a Portable class library